# PHP SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I've read in several places that htmlspecialchars is not enough to prevent SQL injection attacks. I'm working with a legacy codebase and it uses this to sanitize user input:

```
stripslashes(htmlspecialchars(trim($value), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))
```

My gut tells me that this is also unsafe but my coworker insists that it is. I don't have much experience in working with plain PHP so could someone please tell me why this is unsafe so that I can convince my coworker to use something better?

Answer (score 1):

> I've read in several places that htmlspecialchars is not enough to prevent SQL injection attacks

It protects against XSS attacks, but SQL is not HTML so it does nothing for SQL injection.

(You should move the htmlspecialchars encoding to "before inserting into HTML" instead of "before inserting into SQL")

> My gut tells me that this is also unsafe but my coworker insists that it is.

Your gut is right. The fact it leaves quote characters alone shouts **unsafe!**.

Take a look at [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). It demonstrates the problem and provides a number of solutions. Anything that uses bound parameters is good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does seem to escape quotes, for example, a single quote is converted to: &#039; and a double quote to: &quot;. The developer is slightly hard headed and I need a strong argument to bring him over from the dark side so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although there are many other solutions than htmlspecialchars, I cannot think about any possibility to do sql injection in the presence of htmlspecialchars with ENT_QUOTES when the user input is in single quotes. Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Use [prepared statements](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1%3a_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29).

Answer (score 0):

disable `magic quote` in php.ini and use `PDO`. bum

`htmlspecialchars` to escape params in SQL is the ugliest

Answer (score 0):

It may prevent you from XSS, but not from SQLi, because it doesn't quote any SQL-specific (or DBMS-specific) special characters. The most modern solution is to use [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) with [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) or [`PDO:quote()`](http://php.net/pdo.quote). Legacy solutions cover [`mysql_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql-escape-string) and such. Refer the manual about the db-driver you are using, about the features it provides to prevent you from SQLi.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling a database specific escaping function on things you insert into queries.
For a MYSQL database, use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the type of SQL query it is injecting. SQL injections in string fields (enclosed with ' and ") can be disabled by encoding or removing this characters. But in general this is not the solution!

You should NEVER EVER concatenate the SQL string together and send it to the database, especially if it contains user supplied data. You should always use the prepare statement to prepare a SQL statement with placeholders and then pass the parameters separately. Yes, this means that you will probably need to have more than one line of code and you will call corresponding SQL functions.

This is the only good solution for this that is implemented in all programming languages.

Answer (score -1):

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) would be better than [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_escape_string) as it has been deprecated.